# How to add a break in rendering animation after rendering 1 frame in blender

Tags: rendering

my problem is that, i m running a low PC and it's cooling fan is also not works, and i want to render the image sequence, so my question is that, can we just stop the rendering for few minutes after each frame render, so that my PC can cool down and automatically  start rendering another frame after few time, yeh, we can do it manually, but it is very time consuming, as i want to run rendering at night when i go to bed, so i want automatic break of few minutes after each frame render, to prevent my PC from burning.

Comment: I believe this is impossible with blender's current software. The only solution I could think of (which is pretty bad) is to render it as an image sequence and then start the render of each frame by hand.

Comment: You could render using a terminal. Create a script that runs blender and waits and moves on to the next frame. There are no built in tools to do what you want, so you are going to need to get crafty or get a fan for your computer.

Comment: blender Guru suggests you use a render farm where you upload your file and they render it for you and send it back not all that expensive if your computer has issues. You'll have to look through his videos or send him a msg for the name of the org .. there are a few

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable time to answer my question 

Comment: Well i just figure it out (A trick), writing it down so that other might get some help from this :
* Hit render
* Put you PC into sleep  mod and just wake it up, and do not login into computer, this way, Pc resumes rendering without using large amount of resources (rendering may be little slow)
and after some time just login to user again :)

In compositing we can also use output node to automatically save the render